# Cómo puedo insertar mis detalle-factura

Tags: laravel, ajax

tengo una base de datos con una tabla producto la cual contiene su id y otras propiedades. Lo mismo la tabla factura con un id y sus demás propiedades. Entre estas dos tablas hay una relación de mucho a muchos lo cual genera la tabla intermedia detalle-factura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta tabla tiene dos llaves foráneas como lo podrán ver. mi duda es que cada vez que el usuario vaya agregando un detalle o un ítem como hago para insertarlo en la base de datos si necesito el id de la factua y esta aun no se ha creado? o que otra alternativa puedo usar en este caso? Mi proyecto está hecho en laravel y estoy usando ajax porque aun no tengo conocimientos de vue ni de react.

Comment: Agrega lo que lleves al momento por favor

Comment: Con Eloquent y sus relaciones será relativamente simple, tienes los modelos y relaciones creadas?

Comment: Beta m si las tengo. Pero si el usuario selecciona varios ítem como puedo insertarlos todos a la vez?